# animate svg background pattern

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I  want to attempt animating -> http://www.heropatterns.com , namely the circuit-board background pattern. E.g simulate a flowing current on let's 10% of the lines on the board.

So to start off, I tried implementing the following -> secured://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works which resulted in the following non-working code:

**svg**

```
<svg width="304px" height="304px" viewBox="0 0 304 304" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<!-- Generator: Sketch 40 (33762) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
<title>Artboard 3 Copy 2</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="Artboard-3-Copy-2" fill="#000000">
        <path class="path" d="M44.1000181...>
```

**css**

```
body{
background-color: #DFDBE5;
background-image: url("icons/circuit-board.svg");
}
.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Is this possible on a background pattern? Am I missing something or on the right track?

I would like the flow of the current..if possible to behave somewhat like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hstqcrgk/

Comment: this is a good tutorial I read recently: https://codepen.io/rachsmith/post/my-process-for-building-generative-pens maybe it helps you with how to animate svg via javascript. btw is your question about css animations or svg manipulation via javascript?

Comment: You cannot style the contents of an external image like that. CSS does not cross file boundaries.

Comment: You'd need to put the CSS animation in the SVG document itself.

Answer (score 0):

For whats worth I made a similar code snippet just like what you're referring to. You can check out a live version of it here. https://infographic.koalafiedcoder.com/animation/board

But basically you need to animate a basic line and manually draw them. You can do this using **3 overlapping SVGs** and animate it through the **stroke-dasharray**, **stroke-dashoffset** and the stroke color. Afterwards, manually plot those lines on an SVG. If you want to have it symmetrically design, I suggest applying a temporary coordinate points on top of you SVG.

I actually made a blog post about this if you want to go into detail. 
[Animating a Basic Line](https://www.koalafiedcoder.com/blogs/line-animation) and [Drawing a Circuit Board](https://www.koalafiedcoder.com/blogs/circuit-board)